# Ho to Split a string by Multiple tag then process it one by one

Tags: string, split

i'm looking for a way to split a string of multiple tag into a separate string to process it one by one
for example when a string og tag "[{M}sometag] [sometag] [{F}sometag]" is coming is should separate firstly from the "[" then leave just {M}sometagand process one by one.... any idea?

Comment: You mean getting three items in resultset i.e. {M}sometag, sometag and {F}sometag?

Comment: i'm going to get a string like this



string s = "hello [sometag] how are you? i'm fine and you MS.[sometag]"



what i need is to get the part from [ to ] and replace with a name that i have already stored, but what i'm getting confused in, is how to search through the string "s" and get only the tag contained between [ ], in this case "[sometag]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pseudo code to give you a direction:

We have to go through each character, appending to a string, say "result" if we find any character which seems to be a good candidate

A boolean/bool field, say "isCandidate" will be needed, set it to false initially

1. Check if current character is not '['

   i. Check if current character's previous character is a '['

   ```
       a. Append previous character (i.e. '[') to result

       b. Set isCandidate to true
   ```

   ii. Check if isCandidate is true

   ```
   a. Check if current character is not a ']'

       1) Append current character (i.e. anything not a '[' or ']') to result

   b. Check if current character is a ']'

       1) Append current character (i.e. ']') to result

       2) Set isCandidate to false (You have found your first word closed within '[' and ']')

       3) Add the result string in a list or array (or any structure where you'd be maintaining your results)

       4) Set result to empty string
   ```
2. Repeat for the next character until end of string is reached

Answer (score 0):

thank's you for your help

by following your advice i did something like this

```
    public string Extract(string in_tag)
    {
        string current  = in_tag;
        bool isCandidate = false;
        string tempstring;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < current.Length; i++)
        {
            char c= current[i];

            if(c== '[')
            {
                isCandidate = true;
            }

            if(isCandidate)
            {
                result.Append(c);
                if(c == ']')
                {
                    tempstring = result.ToString();
                    result.Clear();
                    for (int j = 0; j < _entriesAry.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if(_entriesAry[j].IsMatchTag(tempstring))
                        {
                            current.Replace(tempstring,_entriesAry[j].ReplacedWord());
                        }
                    }
                    isCandidate = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return current;
    }
```

but i didn't get the expected results

Comment: fixed just by put current = current.Replace(tempstring,_entriesAry[j].ReplacedWord());

thank's you!!